# Are there any number systems better suited to nature?

Tags: irrational-numbers, number-systems

For example, number such as $\pi$ and $e$ cannot be represented as rational numbers in our number study and extend in decimal places to infinity.

**QUESTION:**

Is there a possibility that some other number system can represent fundamental constants present in nature correctly?

Comment: Yes, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-integer_representation#Base_e for $e$, and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-integer_representation#Base_.CF.80 for $\pi$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $e=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{n!}$, you can represent it as $10.111111\dots$ using the [factorial number system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial_number_system).